# How to get variable name and value in AST

Tags: php, debugging, abstract-syntax-tree, php-parser

I'm using [PHP-PArser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) to find the AST of PHP program. For example:

code

```
<?php
use PhpParser\Error;
use PhpParser\NodeDumper;
use PhpParser\ParserFactory;

$code = <<<'CODE'
<?php
$variable = $_POST['first'];
$new = $nonexist; 
CODE;

$parser = (new ParserFactory)->create(ParserFactory::PREFER_PHP7);
try {
    $ast = $parser->parse($code);
} catch (Error $error) {
    echo "Parse error: {$error->getMessage()}\n";
    return;
}

$dumper = new NodeDumper;
echo $dumper->dump($ast) . "\n";
```

The AST result of the above example as following:

```
array( 0: Stmt_Expression( expr: Expr_Assign( var: Expr_Variable( name: variable ) expr: Expr_ArrayDimFetch( var: Expr_Variable( name: _POST_first_symbol ) dim: Scalar_String( value: first ) ) ) ) 1: Stmt_Expression( expr: Expr_Assign( var: Expr_Variable( name: new ) expr: Expr_Variable( name: nonexist ) ) ) )
```

What I'm trying to find is the `variable = _POST` AND `new = nonexist`
I used `leavenode` function to reach `_POST` and `variable`. my code to find `_POST`and `variable` as following:

```
public function leaveNode(Node $node)
    {
        $collect_to_print= array();

        if ($node instanceof ArrayDimFetch
            && $node->var instanceof Variable
            && $node->var->name === '_POST')
        {
            $variableName = (string) $node->var->name;
            $collect_to_print[$node->dim->value] = $node->var->name; // will store the variables in array in a way to print them all later such as variable => _POST , how to get the name `variable` in this case
            return $node;
        }
        else
            if ($node instanceof Variable
        && !($node->var->name === '_POST' ))
        {
            $collect_to_print[$node->name] = 'Empty' ;
        }

    }
```

My results until now show every variable in separate line as following:

```
variable => 
first => _POST  // This _POST should be the value of variable (above)
new => Empty
nonexist => Empty
```

However, I expect the result to be:

```
variable => _POST
new => Empty
nonexist => Empty
```

any help please

Comment: Why would you expect `variable => _POST` and then not get `new => nonexist`?

Comment: I mean to get all nodes with its values

Comment: It keep consider `_POST` as  separated variable. However, I want the `_POST` to be considered as value not separated variable

Comment: I want to store them in array like `$collect_to_print[variable] = _POST` , `$collect_to_print[new] = Empty`, `$collect_to_print[nonexist] = Empty`

Comment: I search for any variable in the code. Once found, then get the value of that variable and store it in array with key index(name of that variable). If the value is another normal variable, so store each variable in the array with its values. However, I want to consider the global variable as value for the variable above, not new variable with value.

Comment: Is there any progress with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lot more complicated than other questions you've asked, but it has been interesting to learn about how to write it.

I've put comments through the code, but basically it analyses the code and looks for assignments (instances of `PhpParser\Node\Expr\Assign` nodes).  It then splits it into left and right parts and recursively extracts any variables in either parts.

The code allows for nested variables on either side of the expression, I've changed the example code to provide some broader examples.

Comments in code (assumes some knowledge of how the parser works with nodes etc.)...

```
$traverser = new NodeTraverser;

class ExtractVars extends NodeVisitorAbstract {
    private $prettyPrinter = null;

    private $variables = [];
    private $expressions = [];

    public function __construct() {
        $this->prettyPrinter = new PhpParser\PrettyPrinter\Standard;
    }

    public function leaveNode(Node $node) {
        if ( $node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Expr\Assign  ) {
                $assignVars = $this->extractVarRefs ( $node->var );
                // Get string of what assigned to actually is
                $assign = $this->prettyPrinter->prettyPrintExpr($node->var);
                // Store the variables associated with the left hand side
                $this->expressions[$assign]["to"] = $assignVars;
                // Store variables from right
                $this->expressions[$assign][] = $this->extractVarRefs ( $node->expr );
         }
    }

    private function extractVarRefs ( Node $node ) : array  {
        $variableList = [];
        // If it's a variable, store the name
        if ( $node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Expr\Variable )   {
            $variable = $this->prettyPrinter->prettyPrintExpr($node);
            $this->variables[] = $variable;
            $variableList[] = $variable;
        }
        // Look for any further variables in the node
        foreach ( $node->getSubNodeNames() as $newNodeName )   {
            $newNode = $node->$newNodeName;
            if ( $newNode instanceof Node && $newNode->getSubNodeNames())   {
                // Recursive call to extract variables
                $toAdd = $this->extractVarRefs ( $newNode );
                // Add new list to current list
                $variableList = array_merge($variableList, $toAdd);
            }
        }
        return $variableList;
    }

    public function getVariables() : array  {
        return array_unique($this->variables);
    }

    public function getExpressions() : array    {
        return $this->expressions;
    }

}

$varExtract = new ExtractVars();
$traverser->addVisitor ($varExtract);

$traverser->traverse($ast);

print_r($varExtract->getVariables());

print_r($varExtract->getExpressions());
```

Which gives the list of variables as...

```
Array
(
    [0] => $_POST
    [1] => $b
    [3] => $new
    [4] => $nonexist
)
```

And the list of expressions as

```
Array
(
    [$_POST[$b]] => Array
        (
            [to] => Array
                (
                    [0] => $_POST
                    [1] => $b
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => $_POST
                )

        )

    [$new] => Array
        (
            [to] => Array
                (
                    [0] => $new
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => $nonexist
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => $_POST
                    [1] => $b
                )

        )

)
```

note that the `[to]` element of the array contains any variables involved on the left of the `=`.